# What happens when I call UnitySendMessage and game object was destroyed?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am developing Unity3d plugin. And I wonder what happens if I call
UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage and gameObject was destroyed?

Comment: "Trying" is always better than "wondering".

Answer (score 1):

When you call `UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage` and if the Object provided is destroyed or cannot be found, it would throw a simple error that says *`"object <objectname>not found"`*.

Now, it throws "`SendMessage: Object <objectname> is not found!`" as the error error